# HtmlCollections. Get from collection elemetns. | TypeScript & Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have in HtmlCollection 3 elements of html type. I converted it to an array. I want to get from this array all elements where attribute aria-expanded=true. But I have some problems. When I printed it on console I have this.

https://prnt.sc/pqrjpd

I dont know why if in two aria-expanded=true but I have three "true". How I can get from this array only with true on TypeScript. My code

```
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('pi-caret-down');
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(y);
for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
   this.divOpen = arr[index].closest('li > div');
  console.log(this.divOpen);
  console.log(this.divOpen.getAttribute('aria-expanded'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('div.pi-caret-down[aria-expanded="true"]')`

Comment: It didnt help :(